# Laplace transform of piecewise function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a piecewise function `f_i(t)`, where `sigma_i` and `tau` are constants (`i` is the subscript). 
[image]

I have two questions regarding its Laplace transform in Matlab:

1. How can I represent a piecewise function in Matlab so that
2. Matlab can compute its Laplace transform by `laplace()` function?

I have tried using `heaviside()` in Matlab to help represent the piecewise function `f_i(t)`:
(`>>` is the prompt in Matlab)

```
>> syms sigma t tau
>> f=heaviside(t-tau)*(1-exp(-sigma*(t-tau)))
```

Then I get:

```
>> laplace(f, t, s)

ans =

laplace(heaviside(t - tau)*exp(-sigma*(t - tau))*(exp(sigma*(t - tau)) - 1), t, s)
```

Obviously, the Laplace transform is not actually computed.

Is there any other way I can compute the Laplace transform of a piecewise function in Matlab?

Comment: It can be done in numerically. MATLAB is not a tool of choice for symbolic computations, I would say

Comment: What do you mean by `numerically`? And, is there any tool suitable for this?

Comment: Numerically means that you don't use syms and your t is represented by an array and sigma and tau are well defined numbers. For numerical computations MATLAB suits very good, IMHO; for symbolical ones one can use mathematica, maple etc. In symbolical computations the answer is usually represented by an symbolic expression, while in numerical computations it is an array of numbers. So what do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, then I must say I want symbolic answer. I will try Mathematica.